# How do pass a tibble to a function and calculate conditional Sumifs

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to write a function that will calculate a score from a baseball player's splits.  I have created the splits Tibble, a working Tibble, and a function to use along with the mutate function to add a score column to the working Tibble, df.

The function is supposed to take the input from the working Tibble and calculate a score (sum of averages) based upon the relevant splits. I have provided the following reprex.  When I try to execute my function I am producing scores of zero.  The expected score values follow the reprex.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```r
library(tidyverse)

split <- tibble(player=c("Soto","Soto","Judge","Judge","Soto","Soto","Judge","Judge"),
                split=c("Grass","Turf","Grass","Turf","DAY","NIGHT", "DAY","NIGHT"),
                AVG=c(200,225,250,275,300,325,350,375))
df <- tibble(date = c("2021-03-24", "2021-03-27", "2021-03-21", "2021-03-25"), player=c("Soto","Soto", "Judge", "Judge"), TOD=c("DAY","DAY","DAY","NIGHT"), surface=c("Grass","Turf","Turf","Grass"))

split
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   player split   AVG
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 Soto   Grass   200
#> 2 Soto   Turf    225
#> 3 Judge  Grass   250
#> 4 Judge  Turf    275
#> 5 Soto   DAY     300
#> 6 Soto   NIGHT   325
#> 7 Judge  DAY     350
#> 8 Judge  NIGHT   375

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   date       player TOD   surface
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 2021-03-24 Soto   DAY   Grass  
#> 2 2021-03-27 Soto   DAY   Turf   
#> 3 2021-03-21 Judge  DAY   Turf   
#> 4 2021-03-25 Judge  NIGHT Grass

getSplitScore <- function(df,player,surface, timeofDay){
 
  z <- sum(df[df$player==player & df$split==timeofDay,]$AVG)
  y <- sum(df[df$player==player & df$split==surface,]$AVG)
  
  return(z + y)
}


df <- df %>% 
  mutate(score=getSplitScore(split, player, surface, TOD))

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   date       player TOD   surface score
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <int>
#> 1 2021-03-24 Soto   DAY   Grass       0
#> 2 2021-03-27 Soto   DAY   Turf        0
#> 3 2021-03-21 Judge  DAY   Turf        0
#> 4 2021-03-25 Judge  NIGHT Grass       0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What I am expecting is this:

```
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   date       player TOD   surface score
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <int>
#> 1 2021-03-24 Soto   DAY   Grass     500
#> 2 2021-03-27 Soto   DAY   Turf      525
#> 3 2021-03-21 Judge  DAY   Turf      625
#> 4 2021-03-25 Judge  NIGHT Grass     625
```

Comment: You don't have a column `BaVG` in the `split` tibble. I'm also not sure how you arrive at the score values.

Comment: In your desired output the score of 200 are the sum of Soto Day & Soto TOD? I just need an example on how the score is calculated.

Comment: The score is simply the sum of the to split BaVG/

Comment: @WilliamGram Good catch. Sometimes you can just be too close to things.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `group_by` before executing mutate in pipe will work.  See

```
df %>% group_by(date, player) %>%
  mutate(score= getSplitScore(split, player, surface, TOD))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   date, player [4]
  date       player TOD   surface score
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-03-24 Soto   DAY   Grass     500
2 2021-03-27 Soto   DAY   Turf      525
3 2021-03-21 Judge  DAY   Turf      625
4 2021-03-25 Judge  NIGHT Grass     625
```

Alternate strategy proposed

```
df %>% left_join(split, by = c("player" = "player", "TOD" = "split")) %>%
  rbind(df %>% left_join(split, by = c("player" = "player", "surface" = "split"))) %>%
  group_by(date, player, TOD, surface) %>%
  summarise(AVG = sum(AVG))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   date, player, TOD [4]
  date       player TOD   surface   AVG
  <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 2021-03-21 Judge  DAY   Turf      625
2 2021-03-24 Soto   DAY   Grass     500
3 2021-03-25 Judge  NIGHT Grass     625
4 2021-03-27 Soto   DAY   Turf      525
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. My function is supposed to reference the split df.  I'm not trying to summarize columns in df, I'm trying to calculate a score from the AVG column in the split when the surface and time of day in df and split match.

Comment: Yes. Got it.  See my revised answer.  Just add a `group_by` before `mutate` in dplyr pipe, and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by splitting your `split$split` column into turf and day. One less elegant approach:

```
split <- split %>% 
  mutate(
    TOD = ifelse(split %in% c('DAY', 'NIGHT'), split, 'NA'),
    surface = ifelse(split %in% c('Grass', 'Turf'), split, 'NA'),
    .keep = 'unused'
  )
```

Then you could left join:

```
df <- df %>% 
  left_join(
    split %>% select(-surface) %>% rename(todVal = AVG), by = c('player', 'TOD')
  ) %>% 
  left_join(
    split %>% select(-TOD) %>% rename(surfaceVal = AVG), by = c('player', 'surface')
  ) %>% 
  mutate(score = (todVal + surfaceVal), .keep='unused')
```

The output you should get:

```
df
#         date player   TOD surface score
# 1 2021-03-24   Soto   DAY   Grass 500.0
# 2 2021-03-27   Soto   DAY    Turf 525.0
# 3 2021-03-21  Judge   DAY    Turf 625.0
# 4 2021-03-25  Judge NIGHT   Grass 625.0
```

I do see that the output is not what you wanted, but perhaps you should try to be a bit clearer on what you are trying to do.